# Rider - Continue from breakpoint

Tags: rider

When hitting a breakpoint during runtime I want to continue afterwards. When using Visual Studio I continue by pressing **F5**. What is the correct button or key to continue with Rider?

[image]

I was not able to find a button that does it. The "resume" button would run the project again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rider it is done with F9 "Resume program".

[image]